# Should I use wsprintf() to print a double as a wide string?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am unable to print `double` value using `wsprintf()`.
I tried `sprintf()` and it worked fine.

Syntax used for `wsprintf()` and `sprintf()` is as follows:

```
wsprintf(str,TEXT("Square is %lf "),iSquare); // Does not show value

sprintf(str," square is %lf",iSquare);  // works okay
```

Am I making any mistakes while using `wsprintf()` ?

Comment: Is `str` a wide character string?

Comment: @PascalCuoq: In this context, a Windows (Microsoft) macro that expands to `L`. Rather verbose and error-prone.

Comment: `"%Lf"` is for `long double` arguments. Use plain `"%f"` for a `double` argument. I'm not sure if `"%lf"` is valid in standard C++.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`wsprintf` doesn't support floating point. The mistake is using it at all.

If you want something like `sprintf`, but for wide characters/strings, you want `swprintf` instead.

Actually, since you're using the `TEXT` macro, you probably want `_stprintf` instead though: it'll shift from a narrow to wide implementation in sync with the same preprocessor macros as `TEXT` uses to decide whether the string will be narrow or wide. This whole approach, however, is largely a relic from the days when Microsoft still sold and supported versions of Windows based on both the 32-bit NT kernel, and on the 16-bit kernel. The 16-bit versions had only extremely minimal wide-character support, so Microsoft worked hard at allowing a single source code base to be compiled to use either narrow characters (targeting 16-bit kernels) or wide characters (to target the 32-bit kernels). The 16-bit kernels have been gone for long enough that almost nobody really has much reason to support them any more.

For what it's worth: `wsprintf` is almost entirely a historic relic. The `w` apparently stands for `Windows`. It was included as part of Windows way back when (back to the 16-bit days). It was written without support for floating point because at that time, Windows didn't use any floating point internally--this is part of why it has routines like [MulDiv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-muldiv) built-in, even though doing (roughly) the same with floating point is quite trivial.

Comment: Heck, it ran on quite a few systems which didn't have floating point hardware at all. Even Windows 95 supported the 80386 without a 387 FPU.

Comment: Yes, It works. I have used the "_stprintf_s" this method is exactly what I want. Thanks for your help. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k.aspx

Comment: "It was included as part of Windows way back when (back to at least Windows 2.1, probably Windows 1)." Not true. It was first available in Windows 3.0, not Windows 2.x nor 1.x.

Comment: @raymai97: I'll have to take your word for it. I lost all the docs I had on pre-32-bit Windows 3 or 4 moves ago...

Comment: I would advise the OP just to drop the `TEXT` and `T` macros entirely, unless source-code compatibility with versions of Windows from the early ’90s really, truly is a requirement.

Answer (score 3):

The function `wsprintf()` does not support floating point parameters, try using `swprintf()` instead if you're working with floating point values.

More information about swprint can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybk95axf%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

`wsprintf` does not support floating point.  See its [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647550%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - `lf` is not listed as a valid format code.

The [swprintf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybk95axf%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function part of the Visual Studio standard library is what you want.  It supports all of the format codes that `sprintf` does.

Answer (score -2):

Presumably you're not compiled to UNICODE and TEXT is #defined to just a regular string.

Comment: I downvoted since the answer was wrong. But it did not look like you put much effort into finding out about `wsprintf()`.

Comment: You are correct, I did not research wsprintf.  Clearly OP did not either.  I took a guess and I was wrong; I'll leave for posterity.